# I'm having this error when I try to update/edit the Sqlite database java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 can any on help me

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm having this error when I try to update/edit the Sqlite database java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0  can any on helping me.
when I try to delete the existing data from the database it works. But when I try to update or edit the existing data from the database, it does not work and the app crashes.

when I check the database inspector then I find one thing that when I try to edit the table data on the database the Class_table will gone or you can say delete automatically. and I don't find any solution for this problem can anyone help me plz.

**Here is the error code:**

```
    Process: com.example.attendance, PID: 20112
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.example.attendance.MainActivity.updateClass(MainActivity.java:135)
        at com.example.attendance.MainActivity.lambda$showUpdateDialog$4$MainActivity(MainActivity.java:131)
        at com.example.attendance.-$$Lambda$MainActivity$m9twlugKZZaVnr6kCG8LrRCoXMM.onClick(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.example.attendance.MyDialog.lambda$getUpdateClassDialog$1$MyDialog(MyDialog.java:94)
        at com.example.attendance.-$$Lambda$MyDialog$5v1iqgaO8riJO2phwUfadWXdoyM.onClick(Unknown Source:6)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:8160)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:16222)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:8137)
        at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:888)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30236)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 20112 SIG: 9
```

**Here is My Activity:**

```
package com.example.attendance;
    
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
    
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toolbar;
    
    import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    
        FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        ClassAdapter classAdapter;
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
        ArrayList<ClassItem> classItems = new ArrayList<>();
        Toolbar toolbar;
        DbHelper dbHelper;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    
            dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
    
            floatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab_main);
            floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(V -> showDialog());
    
            loadData();
    
    
            recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.att_list);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            classAdapter = new ClassAdapter(this, classItems);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(classAdapter);
            classAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(position -> gotoItemActivity(position));
    
            setToolbar();
    
        }
    
        private void loadData() {
            Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getClassTable();
    
            classItems.clear();
            while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.C_ID));
                String department = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.CLASS_NAME_KEY));
                String subject = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.SUBJECT_NAME_KEY));
    
                classItems.add(new ClassItem(id,department,subject));
            }
    
        }
    
        private void setToolbar() {
    
            toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    
            TextView title = toolbar.findViewById(R.id.tool_title);
            TextView subTitle = toolbar.findViewById(R.id.tool_sub_title);
            TextView samiTitle = toolbar.findViewById(R.id.tool_sami_title);
            ImageButton back = toolbar.findViewById(R.id.tool_back);
            ImageButton save = toolbar.findViewById(R.id.tool_save);
    
            title.setText("Attendance");
            subTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            samiTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            save.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            back.setOnClickListener(v -> onBackPressed());
    
        }
    
        private void gotoItemActivity(int position) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,StudentActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("departmentName",classItems.get(position).getDepartment());
            intent.putExtra("subjectName",classItems.get(position).getSubject());
            intent.putExtra("position",position);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    
        private void showDialog() {
            MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
            dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),MyDialog.CLASS_ADD_DIALOG);
            dialog.setListener((department,subject)->addClass(department,subject));
    
        }
    
        private void addClass(String department, String subject) {
            long cid = dbHelper.addClass(department,subject);
            ClassItem classItem = new ClassItem(cid,department,subject);
            classItems.add(classItem);
            classAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean onContextItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case 0:
                    showUpdateDialog(item.getGroupId());
                case 1:
                    deleteClass(item.getGroupId());
            }
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    
        private void showUpdateDialog(int position) {
            MyDialog updateDialog = new MyDialog();
            updateDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),MyDialog.CLASS_UPDATE_DIALOG);
            updateDialog.setListener((department,subject)->updateClass(position,department,subject));
        }
    // when I try to Update the Data its don't work and the app will crash
        private void updateClass(int position, String department, String subject) {
            dbHelper.updateClass(classItems.get(position).getCid(),department,subject);
            classItems.get(position).setDepartment(department);
            classItems.get(position).setSubject(subject);
            classAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
        }
    
        private void deleteClass(int position) {
            dbHelper.deleteClass(classItems.get(position).getCid());
            classItems.remove(position);
            classAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }
    }
```

**Here is my Adepter**

```
     package com.example.attendance;
        
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.view.ContextMenu;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        
        import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
        import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
        
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        
        public class ClassAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ClassAdapter.ClassViewHolder> {
        
            private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
        
            public interface OnItemClickListener {
                void onClick(int position);
            }
        
            public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
                this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
            }
        
            public ClassAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ClassItem> classItems) {
                this.classItems = classItems;
                this.context = context;
            }
        
            ArrayList<ClassItem> classItems;
            Context context;
        
            public static class ClassViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnCreateContextMenuListener {
        
        
        
                TextView department, subject;
        
                public ClassViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView,OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        
                    super(itemView);
        
                    department = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dep_tv);
                    subject = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sub_tv);
                    itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> onItemClickListener.onClick(getAdapterPosition()));
                    itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
        
                }
        
                @Override
                public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
                    menu.add(getAdapterPosition(),0,0,"EDIT");
                    menu.add(getAdapterPosition(),1,0,"DELETE");
                }
            }
        
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public ClassViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.class_item, parent, false);
                return new ClassViewHolder(itemView, onItemClickListener);
            }
        
            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ClassViewHolder holder, int position) {
        
                holder.department.setText(classItems.get(position).getDepartment());
                holder.subject.setText(classItems.get(position).getSubject());
        
            }
        
            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return classItems.size();
            }
        }
```

**Here is Database**

```
    package com.example.attendance;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int VERSION = 1;



    //Class table

    private static final String CLASS_TABLE_NAME= "CLASS_TABLE";
    public static final String C_ID= "_CID";
    public static final String CLASS_NAME_KEY= "CLASS_NAME";
    public static final String SUBJECT_NAME_KEY= "SUBJECT_NAME";

    private static final String CREATE_CLASS_TABLE=
            "CREATE TABLE " + CLASS_TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                    C_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, " +
                    CLASS_NAME_KEY + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    SUBJECT_NAME_KEY + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    " UNIQUE ( " + CLASS_NAME_KEY + "," + SUBJECT_NAME_KEY + ")" +
                    ");";

    private static final String DROP_CLASS_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+CLASS_TABLE_NAME;
    private static final String SELECT_CLASS_TABLE = "SELECT * FROM "+CLASS_TABLE_NAME;

    //Student table

    private static final String STUDENT_TABLE_NAME= "STUDENT_TABLE";
    private static final String S_ID= "_SID";
    private static final String STUDENT_NAME_KEY= "STUDENT_NAME";
    private static final String STUDENT_ROLL_KEY= "ROLL";

    private static final String CREATE_STUDENT_TABLE=
            "CREATE TABLE "+ STUDENT_TABLE_NAME +
            "( "+
            S_ID+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "+
            C_ID + " TEXT NOT NULL, "+
            STUDENT_NAME_KEY + " TEXT NOT NULL, "+
            STUDENT_ROLL_KEY + " INTEGER, "+
            " FOREIGN KEY ( "+C_ID+ " ) REFERENCES "+ CLASS_TABLE_NAME + "("+C_ID+")"+
            ");";

    private static final String DROP_STUDENT_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+STUDENT_TABLE_NAME;
    private static final String SELECT_STUDENT_TABLE = "SELECT * FROM "+STUDENT_TABLE_NAME;

    //Status table

    private static final String STATUS_TABLE_NAME= "STATUS_TABLE";
    private static final String STATUS_ID= "_STATUS_ID";
    private static final String DATE_KEY= "STATUS_NAME";
    private static final String STATUS_KEY= "STATUS";

    private static final String CREATE_STATUS_TABLE=
            "CREATE TABLE "+STATUS_TABLE_NAME+
                    "("+
                    STATUS_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "+
                    S_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "+
                    DATE_KEY + " DATE NOT NULL, "+
                    STATUS_KEY + " TEXT NOT NULL, "+
                    " UNIQUE ( " + S_ID + "," + DATE_KEY + ")," +
                    " FOREIGN KEY ( "+ S_ID+ " ) REFERENCES "+ STUDENT_TABLE_NAME + "( "+S_ID+")"+
                    ");";

    private static final String DROP_STATUS_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ STATUS_TABLE_NAME;
    private static final String SELECT_STATUS_TABLE = "SELECT * FROM "+ STATUS_TABLE_NAME;

    public DbHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, "Attendance.db", null, VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CLASS_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_STUDENT_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_STATUS_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        try {
            db.execSQL(DROP_CLASS_TABLE);
            db.execSQL(DROP_STUDENT_TABLE);
            db.execSQL(DROP_STATUS_TABLE);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    long addClass(String className,String subjectName){
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(CLASS_NAME_KEY,className);
        values.put(SUBJECT_NAME_KEY,subjectName);

        return database.insert(CLASS_TABLE_NAME,null,values);
    }

    Cursor getClassTable(){
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        return database.rawQuery(SELECT_CLASS_TABLE,null);
    }

    int deleteClass(long cid){
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        return database.delete(CLASS_TABLE_NAME,C_ID+"=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(cid)});
    }

    long updateClass(long cid,String className,String subjectName){
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(CLASS_NAME_KEY,className);
        values.put(SUBJECT_NAME_KEY,subjectName);

        return database.update(CLASS_TABLE_NAME,values,C_ID+"=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(cid)});
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes I understand what this exception message tried to tell me.

Answer (score 0):

After dropping your tables, you forgot to create them again in your `onUpgrade` method.

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        try {
            db.execSQL(DROP_CLASS_TABLE);
            db.execSQL(DROP_STUDENT_TABLE);
            db.execSQL(DROP_STATUS_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Also it is a good idea to call `.close()` method every time you call `.getWritableDatabase()` or `.getReadableDatabase()`. Here is an example ...

```
long addClass(String className, String subjectName){
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(CLASS_NAME_KEY,className);
        values.put(SUBJECT_NAME_KEY,subjectName);
        database.close();
        long id = database.insert(CLASS_TABLE_NAME,null,values);
        return id;
    }
```

Hope it helps, happy coding!

Comment: Still not Working

Comment: The error message indicates it has something to do with the array having no data. It would be good if you have this project on GitHub or Bitbucket, I can debug it for you.

Comment: I've found the issue. After clicking on "Edit" menu option, your code is also deleting the item. That's why, when your app tries to actually "update" the item, it isn't there anymore.

Comment: Your problem has been fixed. You are not properly breaking your switch statements. Also, instead of trying to add data to your ArrayLists (studentItems, classItems), just call your loadData() method after every database operation. Happy Coding!

Comment: @SkSahil I've posted a new answer, check it out!

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your `MainActivity.class` and `StudentActivity.class`.
In your `onContextItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item)` method, you forgot to `break;` your switch statement.

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 0:
            showUpdateDialog(item.getGroupId());
            break;
        case 1:
            deleteClass(item.getGroupId());
            break;
    } return true;
}
```

Also, instead of adding `classItems` or `studentItems` to their respective ArrayLists after updating or deleting data in your SQLite Database, just call `loadData()` method again!

```
private void deleteClass(int position) {
        dbHelper.deleteClass(classItems.get(position).getCid());
        loadData();
        classAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

private void updateClass(int position, String department, String subject) {
        dbHelper.updateClass(classItems.get(position).getCid(),department,subject);
        loadData();
        classAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

The same thing applies to your `StudentActivity.class`. Happy Coding!